# is there a way to put web-activity result into sql-table (sink)

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

Unable to get the output of a web activity into a sql-table using azure-data-factory.

This is what i have done and where im getting stuck (Step 3).

Steps:
1.Get a token from a API-call

2. Get the results from API Call using token from step 1
   and tkae this results in a successfull query that provides me with  'JSON'
3. Take the result from previous activity 'JSON' and put in in a azure sql database table.

[azure-datafactory - web activites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZMi6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not get this done using a copy activity ? You should configure the source as Web activity and sink as SQL. I was playing with this http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees and we needed to introduce the structure . This is what I did and it work .

```
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RestSource",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010",
                        "structure": [
                            {
                                "id": "id"
                            },
                            {
                                "employee_salary": "employee_salary"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlServerSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },

You can read more . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping
```